# Adding a dynamic link

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to add a new link as following

```
React.Fragment
            li key ={props.items.Poster} img src={props.items.Poster} alt={props.items.Title} li
            li key={props.items.Title}>{props.items.Title} li
            li key={props.items.Year}>{props.items.Year} li
       React.Fragment
```

in the above code, I want to add a link around the image tag. and I want to redirect to another page along with some parameters so that I can use those as props in the other page. Could anyone please let me know how to do this?

Comment: by props in another page, do you mean passing data to another page via the query parameters?

Comment: Hi @DacreDenny yes let's think that way :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, then you could achieve what you require by doing something like this:

```
render() {

    /* Construct href from props data, pass data to new page via query string */
    const { items } = this.props;
    const url = 'someUrl';
    const href = `${ url }?title=${ items.Title }&year=${ items.Year }`;

    /* Wrap img with link and pass dynamically computed href */
    return <React.Fragment>
        <li key ={props.items.Poster}>
            <a href={ href }> 
                <img src={props.items.Poster} alt={props.items.Title}/>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li key={props.items.Title}>{props.items.Title}</li>
        <li key={props.items.Year}>{props.items.Year}</li>
    </React.Fragment>
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @Darce.what if I want to redirect to another component along with the query parameters to use as props.

Comment: For a situation like that I'd suggest client side routing. There are a number of good declarative routing libraries for react, like this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom

Comment: can anyone give an example for the above scenario?

Comment: Using `react-router-dom` ?

Comment: sure - can you include detail for the component you want the link to display?